# Failed to execute 'texSubImage2D' on 'WebGL2RenderingContext': The ArrayBuffer/ArrayBufferView size exceeds the supported range. In flutte web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, arraybuffer

I'm getting this **Failed to execute 'texSubImage2D' on 'WebGL2RenderingContext': The ArrayBuffer/ArrayBufferView size exceeds the supported range.** error after few time I'm developing app in debug mode. I've used Streambuilder in the app.

Here is error details from console

```
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/layer.dart 368:5        paint
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/layer.dart 141:14       paintChildren
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/layer.dart 368:5        paint
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/layer.dart 141:14       paintChildren
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/layer.dart 154:5        paint
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/layer_tree.dart 56:17   paint
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/layer_tree.dart 99:16   <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/profiler.dart 34:18               timeAction
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/layer_tree.dart 98:5    raster
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/rasterizer.dart 33:22   draw
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 585:7    render
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/ui/src/ui/window.dart 94:50                      render
packages/flutter/src/rendering/view.dart 231:15                                                                   compositeFrame
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 501:18                                                                drawFrame
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 883:13                                                                  drawFrame
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 363:5                                                                 [_handlePersistentFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1144:15                                                               [_invokeFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1081:9                                                                handleDrawFrame
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 995:5                                                                 [_handleDrawFrame]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 1011:13  invoke
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 159:5    invokeOnDrawFrame
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/initialization.dart 128:45        <fn>
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
84
Another exception was thrown: Invalid argument: Failed to execute 'texSubImage2D' on 'WebGL2RenderingContext': The ArrayBuffer/ArrayBufferView size exceeds the supported range.
```

I'm stuck with this error for 3 days. Kindly help. I'm using any ArrayBuffer in project.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this error by rendering through **--web-render html** using this command
**flutter build web --web-renderer html --release**